# Why is comparison to True/False using the "is" operator bad?

Tags: python

PEP8 states that checks for `None` should be performed using `is None`. The same holds true for singletons in general. But PEP8 also states, that equality to True and False should not be performed using an operator, `is` being even worse than `==`:

```
Yes:   if greeting:
No:    if greeting == True:
Worse: if greeting is True:
```

I understand that the first one is the prettiest and most pythonic way, but sometimes i find myself in a situation where i want to explicitly show that i am comparing against `True` or `False`. How is `is` worse than `==` in that situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality operator `==` can be implemented by classes (as well as all other comparison operators), but `is` cannot.

A class could be defined so that some of its instances are equal to `True`, but they will still always fail the `is True` comparison. Consider a bool-like class, for example:

```
class MyBool:
    def __init__(self, is_true):
        self.is_true = bool(is_true)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.is_true == bool(other)

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.is_true
```

This class can make sure that for an instance `a = MyBool(True)`, all of `if a:`, `bool(a)` and `a == True` will behave properly. However, `a is True` will return `False`.

Comment: Note that `__bool__` is Python 3.X and the Python 2.X equivalent is `__nonzero__`. Also, if you're going through the trouble of defining `__bool__`, then `if MyBool()` would still be the most pythonic truthiness test.

Answer (score 3):

`is` is "worse" in this context, because requires exact object. First suggestion allows maximal duck-typing, second allows some typical truthy values, last one disallows you for any duck-typing. Only `True` singleton will pass a comparison.

This comparison is successful:

```
1 == True
```

This comparison is unsuccessful:

```
1 is True
```

Comment: But people would seriously doubt your skills if you wrote `if cond == True:` instead if `if cond:`, or `if cond == False:` instead of `if not cond:`.

Comment: This was the most relevant thing noted in the possible duplicate question in the comment above. It seems like the principle of maximal duck typing is guiding the PEP8 specification.

Comment: @Kay Bad habits have deep roots. I find myself doing the same in other languages as well. I will try to remember avoiding that and maybe rethink my variable/function names if i feel the need to explicitly compare against true/false in the future.